# Highchart legend symbol

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to change the legend with filled color same as series, But having circle marker filled with white color on the series fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lur5tw76/13/, Here the legend and series markers are filled with white color at center, Is there any option not to change legend as marker( legend filled with series color), here is my series option for highcharts

```
series: [{
    data: data,
    color: "#405caa",
    stickyTracking: false,
    marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 6,
        fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: null // The series' or point's color is used when null.
    },
    dataGrouping: {
        forced: true,
        approximation: "sum",
        units: units
    }
}]
```

Comment: Legends items should be identical. Why do you want to change them to something else ?

Comment: We are having another column chart (highchart) in the same page, In which the legend is filled with color, So to be similar legend I want to do so

Comment: So you want the legend icon to be all blue, fill and outline, but series marker to be white fill and blue outline. Correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand. What should look different in the demo that you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the legend item to have a different fill than the series you could wrap the processing of `Legend.colorizeItem` to alter it prior to being colored.

For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lur5tw76/28/)):

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'colorizeItem', function (proceed, item, visible) {
    // Store series fill color
    let old_option = item.options.marker.fillColor

    // Store series line color
    let new_option = item.options.marker.lineColor

    // Overwrite series fill color with line color
    item.options.marker.fillColor = new_option

    // Do colorizeItem with new fill color
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    // Set series fill color back to original value
    item.options.marker.fillColor = old_option
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

Comment: Where can we find out the which needs to be changed through wrap (i.e extending highcharts) based on our current requirement

Comment: @Aarthi this was found looking for the source code to how the legend item was being drawn. The entire source code is available here: http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js General guidelines on how to extend Highcharts can be found here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Will look into it, Thanks